# How to do multiple transaction with multiple prices in single in app purchase id in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I m using in app purchase in my iPhone application, here i have to buy many products with different price levels ,so how can i buy the products with using single id, is it possible? or want to create individual id for all products? plz give me some solutions for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think you can't do this. Apple only provides a single In-App
>   Purchase with Single Price. Although, you can set the multiple in-app
>   purchase in a single app.

Comment: Is this helpful to you?

Comment: Thanks a lot bro!!! Happy coding!!! Can you give up-vote too? +1 for you by me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register individual In-Purchase Product Identifier.